# Feed data into a deployed model in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0

I'm checking the new features of Tensorflow 2.0, and I saw that the `placeholder`s got deprecated. Now is possible to use directly a python object.

```py
# Define the SummatorModule that sum the submitted value with the previously
# submitted one
class SummatorModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SummatorModule, self).__init__()
        self.a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(1, 1)), name='a')

    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, x):
        self.a.assign(self.a + x)
        return self.a
```

As you can see here: `self.a.assign(self.a + x)`, I'm summing `self.a` (which is a **named** `Variable`) with `x` (I assume that under the hood it is converted to a **unnamed** `Variable`).

I can use this module in python in this way:

```py
summator = SummatorModule()
print(summator(number))
print(summator(number))
```

Let's suppose that I deploy this model into the application; so I need to feed the data into the model, but since `x` doesn't have a name I can't take the operation as I was able to do before with `placeholder`. So how can I feed the data into a deployed model in Tensorflow 2.0?

Probably even TF 2.0 server APIs got changed, but I'm not able to find anything about it; I hope that you can clean out my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The new saved_model contains the signature of the input/output. Actually the Tensorflow 2.0 C API is not yet released but probably will be a way to parse the Metadata and get these information.